# OSM, Query for POIs in a building

Tags: openstreetmap, query, overpass-api

How can I construct a query (for example for Overpass) for getting all buildings where inside the building is a node (for example a shop)?

Comment: As far as I know, you can't. However, if you import OSM data first with ogr2ogr into Spatialite or PostGIS or with osm2pgsql into PostGIS you can do the query in a database.

Answer (score 3):

Please see this [link](https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/20841/how-to-query-all-elements-within-an-outline-way-from-overpass-api), which gives some important background information on this question with regards to Overpass API.

Assuming you want to find buildings with `amenity` nodes inside, you could use the following query in [Overpass Turbo](http://overpass-turbo.eu):

```
node({{bbox}})[amenity];is_in;
(way[building](pivot);>;);out;
```

It first checks for all nodes having an `amenity` tag in the current bbox and determines all areas containing those nodes. In the second line we convert areas back to actual ways and filter on ways with `building` tag.

With the Overpass API instance on overpass-api.de this only works for buildings having a `name` tag.  Reason being that the server side area creation process uses some specific extraction rules. Unless the objects matches any of those rules, no area will be created, as in the case for buildings without a `name` tag.

If you need all buildings, you would have to set up your own Overpass API instance and adjust rules/areas_osm3s to your needs.

Comment: Thank you so much for this snippet.

Could you please expand your answer by a description of how is_in and pivot works?

In my use case, I need to display those buildings that contain (or whose parts contain) at least one POI tagged with both office=government and country=EU.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what kind of information you're missing. Basically, the answer already mentioned: `is_in` -> determine all areas containing those nodes. `(pivot)` -> convert areas back to actual ways.

Comment: Thx for getting back @mmd. I try to better understand the code to understand why my results of buildings with EU government offices are incomplete. Rue Montoyer 57 should be part of the output. My 2-liner: http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/MaJ

Comment: Did you already double check my comment above: "With the Overpass API instance on overpass-api.de this **only works for buildings having a `name` tag.**"?

Comment: Just checked it once again. Rue Montoyer 30 is captured and has no, name but an `alt_name` tag. Rue Montoyer 57 also has only an `alt_name`, but is not captured. Is it possible that addr tags make a difference?

Comment: The building used to have a `name` tag and an area was created in the past:  (see the different tags for the way and area: http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/MaX ). Now that the `name` tag is gone, the previous area will not be updated anymore and simply remains there. See this GitHub issue for further details: https://github.com/drolbr/Overpass-API/issues/285#issuecomment-234764265

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is currently no API that offers such operator. You can use planet dumps and process it on your own by testing each POI node (or each building way) for checking the boundaries. Due to the amount of data, this can be pretty timeconsuming.